# Type mismatch in expression in Delphi 7 on SQL append

Tags: sql, delphi

I have a code, that checks the current date when a form is loaded, performs a simple calculation, and appends a SQL in Delphi. It works on Windows 7 with Delphi 7, and on another computer with Xp, but doesn't on 3 other computers with Xp. When the form is loaded it shows a "Type mismatch in expression", and points to the line after the append. What could be the problem?

```
procedure TfmJaunumi.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var d1, d2: TDate; 

begin  
 d1:= Date;  
 d2:= Date-30;  
 With qrJaunumi do
     begin
         Open;
         SQL.Append('WHERE Sanem_datums BETWEEN' + #39 + DateToStr(d1) +
         #39 + 'AND' + #39 + DateToStr(d2) + #39);
         Active := True; 
     end; 
end;
```

Comment: Compare the regional settings on the computers, first of all the date formats

Comment: OT I know, but I just can't stand looking at poorly-formatted code.. If I were reviewing this, I'd make you fix the indenting and put those date assignments on their own lines.
 
http://jcl.delphi-jedi.org/documents/styleguide.html#4.3

Comment: Use parameters in stead of concatenating the SQL statement. This makes it much easier to switch your connection layer, and makes it a lot more difficult for SQL injection attacks to succeed. Depending on your connection layer, the syntax for using parameters varies slightly.

Comment: If the parameterised queries don't fix the problem, I would look at the client library version numbers from the various machines.

Comment: What Database are you connecting to, and using what type of DB connection (dbExpress, dbGo (TADOQuery etc) or BDE) are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately none of the above worked, but the solution was to replace the Format with "yy.mm.dd." instead of "yyyy.mm.dd.", and adding single quotes. Weird, it says the format is "yyyy.mm.dd." everywhere.
The code looks like this now:

```
procedure TfmJaunumi.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var d1, d2: TDate; d3, d4, atd: String;

begin
  d1:= Date;
  d3:= FormatDateTime('yy.mm.dd.',d1);
  d2:= Date-30;
  d4:= FormatDateTime('yy.mm.dd.',d2);
  atd := '''';
  With qrJaunumi do
    begin
      Open;
      SQL.Append('WHERE Sanem_datums BETWEEN'+ atd+d4+atd +'AND'+ atd+d3+atd+';');
      Active := True;
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 6):

As robsoft says, it is probably the internationalisation settings. You could use parameterised queries instead - they are generally simpler if using dates and times.

Also, the `Open` after the with's begin isn't needed - in fact it will open the query without the WHERE clause you are adding.

```
 procedure TfmJaunumi.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

 var d1, d2: TDate; 

 begin  d1:= Date;  d2:= Date-30;  With
 qrJaunumi do
         begin
         SQL.Append('WHERE Sanem_datums BETWEEN :StartDate AND :EndDate');
         // exact expression will vary according to DB connection type.
         // Example is for TADOQuery.
         Parameters.ParamByName('StartDate').Value := d1;
         Parameters.ParamByName('EndDate').Value := d2;
         Active := True; 
         end; 
 end;
```

Answer (score 4):

You may use a prepared statement to overcome any localization problems with date time values. DateToStr depends on the client side. FormatDateTime can fail if the server's localization doesn't accept the date format.

```
procedure TfmJaunumi.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  d1, d2: TDate;
begin
  d1:= Date;
  d2:= Date - 30;
  //qrJaunumi.SQL.Clear; removed because it would remove the "SELECT ... FROM ..." part
  qrJaunumi.SQL.Add('WHERE Sanem_datums BETWEEN :StartDate AND :StopDate ');
  qrJaunumi.Prepared := True;
  qrJaunumi.ParamByName('StartDate').AsDateTime := d1;
  qrJaunumi.ParamByName('StopDate').AsDateTime := d2;
  qrJaunumi.Open; // = qrJaunumi.Active := True;
end;
```

The space after ":StopDate" is important because Delphi has a bug in the parameter parser unless they fixed it in newer versions.

Comment: Andreas - you need to remove the `qrJaunumi.SQL.Clear;`, otherwise we will have a query with only a WHERE clause.

Comment: @Gerry is right, but in fairness, @Andreas wrote code that you'd normally expect to see.  The OP seems to be building the first part of the query elsewhere, probably in the designer (shudder).  IMO, it's poor design to mix design-time SQL with run-time SQL.  It's just a disaster waiting to happen, and maintenance is going to be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

It's almost certainly to do with the local internationalisation settings on those computers - DateToStr will return a string in the local date format (possibly MM/DD/YYYY or DD/MM/YYYY) - and depending on where you are this might not be what you're expecting.

I suspect you'll find that the computers it's not working on think they're in a different country/use a different internationalisation setting to the computers where it's working.

A better solution would be to use FormatDateTime to get the date into a standard format that your SQL Server installation will accept, so there's no chance that any local 'internationalisation' settings can interfere like this.

Comment: I checked the server settings, date formats everywhere where it could make a change, they are the same, but still the error doesn't go away. I even tried various FormatDateTime options. Is there something else that could possibly fix this?

Comment: @Demonick - okay, well we need to compare strings then. Can you get the contents of the SQL.Strings property sent to the clipboard in each case? (Add ClipBrd to your uses clause and then do Clipboard.AsText:=SQL.Text). Or even just ShowMessage then - we really need to compare the actual SQL being generated between a working and non-working case. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had same error and found different solution from MS Support:

SQL.Text:='Delete * from TableName where((kno='+(inttostr(userNo))+')and(Sanem_datums >= # '+(FormatDateTime('mm-dd-yy',d1))+' # ))';  ExecSQL;

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/175258

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please familiarize yourself with how to ask a good question :) Please do a formatting, and wrap your code in a code section :) Good luck :)